# Multiplying an array and a 2-d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, product

I'm trying to multiply an array and a 2d array on java and my program compiles but keeps returning the error java.lang.NullPointerException; null when I try to input anything into it. Here is my code so far:

```
static double[][] productWithDiagonal(double[] a, double[][] b)
{
    double[][] c = new double[3][];

    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[1].length; ++j) {    
                c[i][j] = a[j] * b[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    return c;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You're not giving the second dimension of `c` a dimension, so you're effectively writing `double[][] c = { null, null, null }`.

Comment: `b[1].length` is an array?

Comment: yeah, you are not initializing your columns

Comment: Your array is emty, you can't multiply anything...

Answer (score 2):

This here:

```
double[][] c = new double[3][];
```

Only instantiates your "rows". You need something like

```
double[][] c = new double[3][3];
```

Or more useful probably

```
... c = new double[b.length][b[0].length];
```

instead. But just to be sure: those numbers there matter; you should make sure that *b* for example is really a "regular rectangle" shaped matrix - so that **all** rows have the same number of columns. And of course *a* should have the same number of columns as b, too. You could add such checks in the beginning of your method; to ensure that the shapes of *a* and *b* actually allow for this multiplication!

You see, in Java, a two-dim array is nothing but an array that contains another array. Your initial code would only initiate that "outer" array, leaving the "inner" arrays at **null**.

Comment: It might be better to do `new double[b.length][b[0].length]` (or `b[1]`.length, as that's what the loop guard uses).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but tried this and now when I input arrays I get a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to run it

Comment: Sure: you should understand the sizes of your array and that matrix. And things need to match up. In other words: you have to learn to **read** those exceptions. They tell you **exactly** what is going on. But please understand: this is not a service where you come and we hold hands and debug your whole code with you. Learning to program is exactly that: sitting down, writing code, running into problems ... to then figure ways to resolve them. In that sense you (and me, too) are kinda lucky for not receiving downvotes on talking about such *basic* things here.